# responsive embed multiple videos next to each other and under each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am trying to embed multiple Vimeo videos responsively aside and below each other. When I make use of embed-responsive the videos tend to differ a little in position when I use a couple of different of videos. however when I use the same video in all the divs they align perfectly.

[![here a screenshot of the videos not aligning
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puMf6.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puMf6.jpg)

here is my code

```html
<section id="gallery">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/209390725" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/152162621" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/150922044" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/209398590" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi. Please see my answer, if this code does not effect the Vimeo videos in your site. Then you'll have to edit the Vimeo videos before putting them in the site. https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000710167-Adjusting-the-size-of-the-embedded-player

Answer (score 1):

Try this on in your Stylesheet

```
iframe[src*=vimeo] {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 300px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

That will change the dimensions for all vimeo embeds.

Comment: thank you, this works good. However I need to have 2 videos aside each other covering the page..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with bootstrap. It is because the videos you embed have different size. You should customize the video as explained in this [post](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000710167-Adjusting-the-size-of-the-embedded-player) before using it.

---

There are some issues with the classes you use.

1. `Boostrap-4` has removed all of the `*-xs-*` classes. So `col-xs-12` does not exist in the current version of bootstrap. You should use `col-12` instead of it.
2. It is enough to use `col-sm-6` as it covers all the screens with width more than `576px`.

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-12 gallery">
```